# Generate different event for both select node and delete icon in jqtree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

following is my code :

```
var nodeData = ${jsonArray}; // my json data
$('#tree1')
            .tree(
                    {
                        data : nodeData,
                        autoOpen : 1,
                        onCreateLi : function(node, $li) {                              
                            $li
                                    .find('.jqtree-element')
                                    .append(
                                            '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete" data-node-id="Test"><i class="ico ico-tool-delete"></i></a>');
                        }
                    });

    $('#tree1').bind('tree.click', function(event) {
        if (event.node) {               
            var node = event.node;
            alert("edit");

        }
        $tree.on('click', '.Test', function(e) {
            alert("delete");
        });
    });
```

I want to generate different event when click on node and delete icon.

Currently when I click on node and delete icon both generate same event.

Help me, which changes required in above code.

thanks

Comment: make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: My local machine its running but  jsfiddle.net not running my code. You can see here, https://jsfiddle.net/vkumar111/t1hk53fx/12/

Comment: your fiddle is not working because you forgot to include jquery, and `script` tags are not needed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are trying to select elements with `class` Test but this class is not existing.

Also the delete icon is inside the `li` nodes elements this is why you get the same event fired.

Try to append the delete `a` element like this:

```
$('#tree1').tree({
     data : nodeData,
     autoOpen : 1,
     onCreateLi : function(node, $li) {   
          $li.append(
              '<a href="#" class="delete" data-node-id="Test"><i class="ico ico-tool-delete">Delete</i></a>');
          }
     });
```

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/58ebk8sr/1/)

### Edit:

you can save the node id as data `attribute` while appending the delete element.
Then when you click on a specific delete element get the required node by id:

```
var node = $tree.tree('getNodeById', $(this).data('parent-id'));
```

Then remove this item:

```
$tree.tree('removeNode', node);
```

[new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amani1988/58ebk8sr/3/)

Comment: Hi Amani, thanks for your reply. Here title is not useful for delete node. I need node id when click on delete.

Comment: I think using jstree it would be nicer .. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dpzy8xjb/3/  here you can remove items with mouse right click

Comment: yes but our requirement is different, we need delete icon on same line with each node in jqtree.